# How to be sure about something

Tags: logic, ethics

My friend asked me to count the things I'm sure of. Consider that I counted **16** things. If I tell my friend that I'm sure about **16** things, will it be lie? Because I'm sure that I'm sure about 16 things, so the number of things I'm sure of will be **17**. What should I answer to my friend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how you define "surety". First of all, it seems you are assuming that an axiom of surety is that: if you are "sure of P" then you are "sure of sure of P" (see the transitivity axiom of necessity in S4 modal logic, where □A → □□A). Subsequently, if being "sure of P" is also *equivalent* to being "sure of sure of P" then you can limit the things you are sure of to a finite set (technically a finite set of equivalence classes), of size 16 in this case. If however, "sure P" is not equivalent to "sure sure P" then you have a (countably) infinite number of things you are sure about ("sure P", "sure sure P", "sure sure sure P", etc.). Does this help?

Comment: thank you for the answer. If "sure P" is not equivalent to "sure sure P" and I'm sure at least of one thing should my answer be _infinity_?

Comment: Yes, if also "sure P" also implies "sure sure P" (which seems pretty reasonable).

Answer (score 1):

See Ayer on the right to be sure. AJ Ayer was a famous philosopher who thought you had to be sure of p and to have the right to be sure of p in order to know p.

Comment: Hi Robert, welcome to Philosophy.SE! I removed some parts of your post that invited for discussion and could be labelled 'primarily opinion-based', since this site is primarily for discussing established philosophy, rather than 'doing philosophy ourselves'. In the [help] and the [tour] you can find more information about our format.

Comment: Hi @Robert. Can you provide link to the source?

Comment: If you Google AJ Ayer and The Right to Be Sure PDF, you will find many links. It's a classic reading in epistemology. Sorry that I ventured into doing philosophy, but how can I determine what established philosophy is?

Comment: Can you expand on what you think Ayer has to say on the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ayer gave a contextualist answer to what it means to have the right to be sure. In mathematics, we need a proof. But in perception, we only need to see it in good lighting. Like many analytic philosophers, Ayer wants to account for common usage - or what the man on the street thinks about knowledge. Gettier wrote a paper that attempted to undermine Ayer's definition of knowledge, and many philosophers were convinced. But Ayer held firm and insisted that we only need to refine what it means to have the right to be sure to answer Gettier. However, epistemologists didn't aim for this but rather tried to add another condition for knowledge or to reconceive the analysis.